# use HTTP_X_REAL_IP in .htaccess auth

Tags: apache, http-headers

I have a nginx loadbalancer in front off my webservers thus the REMOTE_ADDR header is being overwritten by the ip of the loadbalancer.

the original ip address is in the HTTP_X_REAL_IP header. I know i can get the header with rewrite rules but is there also a way to use the http header within the allow of an .htaccess Auth method?

```
<Directory "/path/*">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Authentication Required"
  AuthUserFile "/path/authfiles/www-app"
  Require valid-user
  ...
  Allow from HTTP_X_REAL_IP
</Directory>
```

I've tried googling but only came across setifenv (tried it) and rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1):

`Allow` doesn't allow you to pass an HTTP header to it, but it does accept environment variables. You should be able to se the env. variable with a `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule`. I haven't tested it, but something like this could work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_X_REAL_IP} ^.+$
RewriteRule .* - [env=real_ip:%0]
Allow from env=real_ip
```

Comment: I've tried it but can you explain how i can allow only a certain ip?    RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_X_REAL_IP} 213.xxx.xxx.xxx
RewriteRule .* - [E=real_ip:%0]
Allow from E=real_ip

Comment: I am not really sure if I understand the use case for this, but you can change the `^.+$` part to any regular expression you want, e.g., `^213.+$`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^(%IP1|%IP2|%IP3)$ let_me_in
Allow from env=let_me_in
```

where %IP1, %IP2, %IP3 - your IPs.

Sure, you can change the regular expression as you wish or just replace it with one IP, or read more here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_access_compat.html